# Inkscape - Exporting the file to pdf gives empty pdf file (SVG file included)

Tags: inkscape

When I export the following pdf file on Inkscape 0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11) and Ubuntu 18.10, I get an empty pdf file.

The SVG file is [here](https://pastebin.com/q3vEKzyA). On pastebin because it is ~1200 lines, but looks very minimal in a viewer.

Please tell me if this is an unreported bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like bug #1768444: [SVG exports as blank PDF](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1768444).

The problem (as described in the bug) is that your SVG uses an invalid transformation matrix. There are two transformation matrices (in the attribute `transform`) that start with four zeros, which means they are not invertible. The first is:

```
<g id="g2272" aria-hidden="true"
  transform="matrix(0,0,0,0,-66.872582,178.2141)"
  syle="fill:currentColor;stroke:currentColor;stroke-width:0">
```

Note the four leading zeroes.

Unfortunately, the bug is still open, so no solution right now.